# In pycuda, how to distribute the rows of a 2-D array to each threads?

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I am new to pycuda. In my code, each thread needs to calculate a row of a 2-D array. However, as I see in the examples, only the element-based distribution is used. How can I distribute it based on rows of the array?

Comment: Are you asking about `ElementwiseKernel` ? Or general CUDA kernel code?

Comment: A general CUDA kernal.

Answer (score 1):

> .... element-based distribution

That is a very strange terminology to use, given that there is no concept of "distribution" at all in either CUDA or PyCUDA. In CUDA, how input data is treated by a given thread is completely at the discretion of the programmer, there are no predefined "distributions" of any sort.

So in a standard CUDA C kernel (which is what you write in PyCUDA, it is really only an API wrapper and compilation system), you could do something like this for a row major ordered input:

```
__global__ 
void kernel(float* array, int lda)
{
     int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
     int rowid = tid * lda;
     float* row = array + rowid;

     for(int col=0; col<lda; col++) {
         row[col] = ....;
     }
}
```

[Obviously never compiled or tested, use at own risk]

The setup code leaves `row` as a pointer to the first element of a given row of the input array which has a leading dimension of `lda`. Obviously, the code will change for column major storage, I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Sorry for my bad description. And thanks for your reply. It does help me. I will have a try.